# Python: hexadecimal regular expression question

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I want to parse the output of a serial monitoring program called Docklight (I highly recommend it)
It outputs 'hexadecimal' strings: or a sequence of (two capital hex digits followed by a space). the corresponding regular expression is: `([0-9A-F]{2} )+` for example: `'05 03 DA 4B 3F '`

When program detects particular sequences of characters it places comments in the 'hexadecimal ' string. for example:

```
'05 03 04 01 0A  The Header 03 08 0B BD AF  The PAYLOAD 0D 0A  The Footer'
```

comments are strings of the following format `' .+ '` (a sequence of characters preceded by a space and followed by a space)

I want to get rid of the comments. for example, the 'hexadecimal' string above filtered would be:

```
'05 03 04 01 0A 03 08 0B BD AF 0D 0A '
```

how do i go about doing this with A regular expression?

Comment: @SRT: assume no 2letter hexadecimal words in the comments, otherwise input would be ambiguous. However, the comments can contain longer words with (consecutive) hexadecimal digits

Comment: ok.look at greg's answer

Comment: Just a note: what I usually use to test regexes, is this free online tester, which works also with Python expressions (the larger part of python and .net expressions are equal flavors): http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: How can you recommend a package that doesn't have an option for easily-parseable output?

Comment: @JM: I recommend it because it is the only tool i found that can successfully handle killer-load serial communications on a Windows PC.  If the comments (which are user-defined) follow a certain syntax (e.g. enclosing square brackets) then parsing would be cake. this is not the case for my client

Comment: Very surprising Python is not aware of `POSIX` `[[:xdigit:]]` character class :/

Answer (score 4):

You could try [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> a='05 03 04 01 0A  The Header 03 08 0B BD AF  The PAYLOAD 0D 0A  The Footer'
>>> re.findall(r"\b[0-9A-F]{2}\b", a)
['05', '03', '04', '01', '0A', '03', '08', '0B', 'BD', 'AF', '0D', '0A']
```

The `\b` in the regular expression matches a "word boundary".

Of course, your input is ambiguous if the serial monitor inserts something like `THIS BE THE HEADER`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to find all the hexadecimal numbers, assuming the inserted strings won't contain a match:

```
>>> data = '05 03 04 01 0A  The Header 03 08 0B BD AF  The PAYLOAD 0D 0A  The Footer'
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile("[0-9A-F]{2} ")
>>> "".join(pattern.findall(data))
'05 03 04 01 0A 03 08 0B BD AF AD 0D 0A '
```

Otherwise you could use the fact that the inserted strings are preceed by two spaces:

```
>>> data = '05 03 04 01 0A  The Header 03 08 0B BD AF  The PAYLOAD 0D 0A  The Footer'
>>> re.sub("(  .*?)(?=( [0-9A-F]{2} |$))","",data)
'05 03 04 01 0A 03 08 0B BD AF 0D 0A'
```

This uses a look ahead to work out when the inserted string ends.  It looks for either a hexadecimal string surround by spaces or the end of the source string.

Answer (score 0):

Using your regex

```
hexa = '([0-9A-F]{2} )+'
" ".join(re.findall(hexa, line))
```

Answer (score 0):

While you already received two answers that find you all hexadecimal numbers, here's the same with a direct regular expression that finds you all text that does not look like a hexadecimal number (assuming that's two letter/digits in uppercase / lowercase 0-9 and A-F range, followed by a space).

Something like this (sorry, I'm not a pythoneer, but you get the idea):

```
newstring = re.sub(r"[^ ]+(?<![0-9A-Fa-f ]{2}|^.)", "", yourstring)
```

It works by "looking back". It finds every consecutive non-space substring, then negatively looks back with `(?<!....)`. It says: "if the previous two characters were not a hex number, then succeed". The little `^.` at the end prevents to incorrectly match the first character of the string.

### Edit

As suggested by Alan Moore, here's the same idea with a positive lookahead expression:

```
newstring = re.sub(r"(?>\b[0-9A-Fa-f ]{2}\b)", "", yourstring)
```

Comment: It's usually easier (and probably more efficient) to use lookaheads for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Alan, indeed it probably is, but you quicker get false positives. In this case, using the word boundary, it works. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why regexp? More pythonic for me is (fixed for hexdigit not regular digit):

```
command='05 03 04 01 0A  The Header 03 08 0B BD AF  The PAYLOAD 0D 0A  The Footer'
print ' '.join(com for com in command.split()
               if len(com)==2 and all(c.upper() in '0123456789ABCDEF' for c in com))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution that actually uses regex negation? ;)

```
result = re.sub(r"[ ]+(?:(?!\b[0-9A-F]{2}\b).)+", "", subject)
```

Comment: also nice! Quiz: which is uglier, your regex negation or my negative look-behind? lol

Comment: It's too close to call, but if you add word boundaries to yours (which I think you should do), you'll be the clear winner.  Or should I say the *unclear* winner?  ;)

Comment: Your wish is my command, I added them to the lookahead version ;)